# Unable to connect to a load balancer from an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, aws-security-group

I want my EC2 instances in an auto-scaling group to be able to connect to a classic load balancer that has RabbitMQ servers behind it.

Here are my configurations:

EC2s' security group:

`my-private-sg` (`sg-00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`)

Classic load balancer's security group:

`rabbitmq-elb-sg` (`sg-11xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`)

The `rabbitmq-elb-sg` security group contains the following inbound rule

[image]

The RabbitMQ client inside the EC2s can't connect to the load balancer under this configuration.

However, it can connect to the load balancer after I set the source to `AnyWhere`.

[image]

Why does this happen?

This [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules) says

```
Another security group. This allows instances associated with the specified security group to access instances associated with this security group.
```

The EC2s, load balancer, and the EC2s behind the load balancer are in the same VPC.

I use the classic load balancer because I use this [terraform script](https://github.com/ulamlabs/terraform-aws-rabbitmq) to build the RabbitMQ service.

I just checked the log in the classic load balancer, and I see something like the following:

```
2019-10-16T03:45:09.124234Z rabbitmq-elb 54.178.178.85:45990 172.31.39.217:5672 0.000274 0.000008 0.000015 - - 516 604 "- - - " "-" - -
2019-10-16T03:45:10.340119Z rabbitmq-elb 54.178.178.85:46006 172.31.0.79:5672 0.001159 0.000008 0.000015 - - 516 604 "- - - " "-" - -
```

`54.178.178.85` is the public IP of my EC2 instance.

`172.31.39.217` and `172.31.0.79` are the private IPs of the RabbitMQ servers behind the load balancer.

Comment: Is all the descried infrastructure in the same VPC? How are the EC2 instances referring to the Classic Load Balancer -- is it by domain name or IP address? It sounds like they are trying to connect via the load balancer's public IP address instead of its private IP address. Also, is there a reason why you are using a Classic load balancer (it's pretty old these days)?

Comment: Are you able to check if the IP accessing your RabitMQ server is actually your (client) EC2 instance 's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My classic load balancer was an `internet-facing` load balancer. After I change it to `internal`, the security group `rabbitmq-elb-sg (sg-11xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)` work without any problem.

I don't have to write `AnyWhere` in the `Source` field anymore.

The EC2 instances tried to connect to the load balancer through private networks. Adding the EC2s' security group (sg-00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) to the source field of rabbitmq-elb-sg (sg-11xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) only works under private networks.

However, I'm still not sure why using an internet-facing load balancer doesn't work in my situation.

Where can I find the explanation of this phenomenon in [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/)?

Comment: The subnet you're selecting , do they have routing table with IGW route ? This is required for public load balancer

Comment: Yes, the EC2s and the load balancers are located in subnets that all have Internet Gateway in their route tables.